# Upload File accross diff cluster using akka http

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am trying to upload the file using akka-http, It works while I try to upload it on the same system or cluster but now how do I upload it to specific server ?

```
(path("/uploadFile") & post) {
    extractRequestContext {
      ctx => {
        implicit val materializer = ctx.materializer
        implicit val ec = ctx.executionContext
        fileUpload("fileUpload") {
          case (fileInfo, fileStream) =>
            val sink = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("/tmp/sample.jar") resolve fileInfo.fileName)
            val writeResult = fileStream.runWith(sink)
            onSuccess(writeResult) { result =>
              result.status match {
                case Success(_) => complete(s"Successfully written ${result.count} bytes")
                case Failure(e) => throw e
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried using `root@localhost:.` but that throws error 
`[akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(RestService)] Error during processing of request: 'root@localhost:./sample.jar'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response.
[ERROR] [08/24/2017 19:13:04.805] [RestService-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [akka://RestService/user/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-1-0-unknown-operation] Error in stage [akka.http.impl.engine.server.HttpServerBluePrint$ControllerStage@4018d466]: requirement failed: Cannot push port`

Comment: What does your `bindAndHandle` invocation look like?  what does the client code look like?